# What is HOLDS_A relationship in C++?

Tags: c++

Need to understand what does this code do?

```
class FAX {
            :
 };

class MODEM {

    FAX * connect;
    long bps;
    char type;
   public:
      MODEM(long sp, char c, FAX *c) : connect(c)
        {
             bps =sp;
             type =c; 
         }
      };
```

Comment: `MODEM(long sp, char c, FAX *c)` Does your compiler accept same name for two parameters ??

Comment: I've never heard of a "holds-a" relationship, but it sounds like it might be the same as a "has-a" relationship, which means composition.  That's borne out by the code.

Comment: Yes this was a code snippet given to understand HOLDS_A relationship. And I am aware that HOLDS_A relationship is that a class that indirectly contains another object via, a pointer or reference.

Comment: @Raul Andres Yes same name for two parameters

Comment: And Further it was told that connect(c) is a member is constructed independently. what does it mean?

Comment: @JohnDibling: I guess, from the code, that it means a non-owning "has-a" relationship (aggregation rather than composition, in UML-speak).

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problems? As is, "declares two classes" is as correct as just copying the whole C++ standard and the standard literature into an answer.

Comment: A class having Has_A relationship with other class has the  ownership of the contained object. And where ownership defines the responsibility for the creation and destruction of an object. But in case of HOLDS_A relationship where the ownership or who constucts and destroys.

Comment: @Uma This is from CS with C++ by Sumita Arora right? Preparing for CBSE boards?

Comment: @Rohan, I am a tutor. Second your " CS with C++" has MANY MANY Typos. To quote a few like  bytes calculation problems(blindly added bytes of each datatype without considering with or without padding) , Mergesort program  ...apart fromone I posted it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like "HOLDS_A" is a slightly confusing way to refer to the relationship more commonly known as *aggregation*, where one object (here the modem) depends on another (here the fax), but does not own it: the modem doesn't have exclusive access to the fax, and doesn't manage its lifetime. This relationship can be realised in C++ by storing a pointer or reference to the other object, as your code demonstrates. Something else is responsible for creating a fax and providing the modem with a pointer to it.

This can be compared with the stronger relationship of *composition*, where the modem does own the fax. In this case, the fax is regarded as part of the modem, not a separate entity potentially used by many other objects. This relationship can sometimes be realised in C++ by making the fax itself a member of the modem class (so that it really is part of the modem); sometimes a pointer is still needed, but that should be a "smart" pointer such as `std::unique_ptr` to manage the ownership relationship.

Comment: Agreed, but when does the FAX *c gets destroyed? though created by an independent member

Comment: @Uma: That's the responsibility of something else. It must last at least as long as this modem object, and anything else that uses it. (Shared ownership, which C++ embodies via `shared_ptr`, might be appropriate for managing aggregated objects, if there isn't a clear owner).

Comment: Now I got the picture of HOLDS_A relationship implemented in C++, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The HOLDS-A relationship, is a type of relationship where an object holds a pointer or reference to an object of a different type and the two are not related(through inheritance)

In this case, even though  FAX and MODEM are not linked through the mechanism of inheritance (that would be a IS-A relationship), MODEM has a member of type FAX creating a dependency of the class MODEM on the class FAX.

As far as what the code does:

```
        MODEM(long sp, char c, FAX *c) : connect(c)
        {
             bps =sp;
             type =c; 
         }
This is a constructor with parameters for class MODEM.
      -you cannot have mode than one member with the same name so I assume this is a typo
      -the constructor initializes bsp and type memebers expicitly
      -and connect member using a initialization list; almost the same as connect = c;
```

Hope this helps

EDIT:

an example of the HOLDS_A relationship

```
class A
{
// class members;
}


class B
{
  A *aMember;
//other class members
}
```

Comment: Yes I guessed earlier that  it was a typo. I couldn't be confident about it. Unless I get the concept of HOLDS_A relationship a suitable example. With this code I don't understand how HOLDS_A relationship works or implemented . And that's why I asked this question here.

Comment: Is this not HAS_A relationship? where the B has the ownership of object of A.

Comment: OK. But I learnt that HOLDS_A relationship is that a class that indirectly contains another object via, a pointer or reference.

Comment: So that B doesn't have ownership of A. As in B it contains a pointer or reference to A . ..?

Comment: sorry about that; I corrected my answer.

Comment: I agree with this answer as well. But sadly this website does not allow me to accept two answers.

Comment: you can up-vote if it was useful

Comment: To vote up I need 15 reputations, sadly I have only 3.